# Big query on a big mysql database

Tags: mysql

I have a big query to count 3 distinct things on same data table:

```
SELECT leagues.feed_league_id AS mleague, 
       leagues.league_id AS mleague_id, 
       leagues.league_name, countries.feed_name, 
       (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT m2.match_id) 
        FROM `matches` AS m2 
        LEFT JOIN stats ON stats.match_id=m2.match_id 
        LEFT JOIN leagues AS l1 ON m2.feed_league_id=l1.feed_league_id 
        WHERE stats.tipo='Golos1ª2ª' AND 
              m2.status='FT' AND 
              (m2.home_ht_score*1+ m2.away_ht_score*1) >1 AND 
              m2.home_ht_score REGEXP '[0-9]+' AND 
              m2.away_ht_score REGEXP '[0-9]+' AND 
              m2.feed_league_id=mleague
       ) AS Total, 
       (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT m3.match_id) 
        FROM `matches` AS m3 
        LEFT JOIN stats ON stats.match_id=m3.match_id 
        LEFT JOIN leagues AS l1 ON m3.feed_league_id=l1.feed_league_id 
        WHERE stats.tipo='Golos1ª2ª' AND 
              m3.status='FT' AND 
              (m3.home_ht_score*1+ m3.away_ht_score*1) >1 AND 
              (m3.home_ft_score*1+m3.away_ft_score*1)-(m3.home_ht_score*1+ m3.away_ht_score*1)>0 AND 
              m3.home_ht_score REGEXP '[0-9]+' AND 
              m3.away_ht_score REGEXP '[0-9]+' AND 
              m3.feed_league_id=mleague 
       ) AS Golos, 
       (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT m2.match_id) 
        FROM `matches` AS m2 
        LEFT JOIN stats ON stats.match_id=m2.match_id 
        LEFT JOIN leagues AS l1 ON m2.feed_league_id=l1.feed_league_id 
        WHERE DATEDIFF(DATE(NOW()), date)<=4 AND 
              stats.tipo='Golos1ª2ª' AND 
              m2.status='FT' AND 
              (m2.home_ht_score*1+ m2.away_ht_score*1) >1 AND 
              m2.home_ht_score REGEXP '[0-9]+' AND 
              m2.away_ht_score REGEXP '[0-9]+' AND 
              m2.feed_league_id=mleague 
       ) AS LastDays 
FROM leagues 
LEFT JOIN countries ON countries.country_id=leagues.country_id 
GROUP BY leagues.feed_league_id HAVING Total>20 
ORDER BY Golos/Total DESC`
```

**Table "leagues" - 828 records**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `leagues` (
  `league_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `league_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `alt_league_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `league_season` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `feed_league_id` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
  `feed_sub_id` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `country_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`league_id`),
  KEY `league_name` (`league_name`),
  KEY `league_season` (`league_season`),
  KEY `feed_league_id` (`feed_league_id`),
  KEY `country_id` (`country_id`),
  KEY `feed_sub_id` (`feed_sub_id`),
  KEY `alt_league_name` (`alt_league_name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=837
```

**Table "matches" - 125K records**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `matches` (
  `match_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `feed_match_id` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `time` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `updated` datetime NOT NULL,
  `home_team_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `away_team_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `home_ft_score` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
  `away_ft_score` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
  `home_ht_score` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
  `away_ht_score` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
  `country_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `league_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `feed_league_id` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
  `feed_sub_id` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `stage_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `week_number` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `n_updates` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`match_id`),
  KEY `date` (`date`),
  KEY `feed_match_id` (`feed_match_id`),
  KEY `status` (`status`),
  KEY `time` (`time`),
  KEY `updated` (`updated`),
  KEY `home_ft_score` (`home_ft_score`),
  KEY `away_ft_score` (`away_ft_score`),
  KEY `home_ht_score` (`home_ht_score`),
  KEY `away_ht_score` (`away_ht_score`),
  KEY `country_id` (`country_id`),
  KEY `league_id` (`league_id`),
  KEY `stage_id` (`stage_id`),
  KEY `week_number` (`week_number`),
  KEY `home_team_id` (`home_team_id`),
  KEY `away_team_id` (`away_team_id`),
  KEY `feed_league_id` (`feed_league_id`),
  KEY `feed_sub_id` (`feed_sub_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=125231 ;
```

**Table "stats" - 250K records**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `stats` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `match_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `stat` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `equipa` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `tipo_id` smallint(6) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `match_id` (`match_id`),
  KEY `stat` (`stat`),
  KEY `equipa` (`equipa`),
  KEY `tipo_id` (`tipo_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=246459 ;
```

Can someone help me simplifying this query. It takes too long to be executed.
If you need more information, please ask.

Thanks.

Comment: A few hundred thousands records is not trivial, but it is not "big".

Comment: You'd better think of restructuring your database. Either you miss some point of business logic or the point of query. Sorry, just my thought - I didn't dig deep.

Comment: Hi, Gordon. I know that there is databases with a few millions, but with the query that I need, my database is big enough :)

Comment: Hi Alex. Sincerely, I have no ideas where to reestructuring my database. Ok, there are a few fields that I can make the varchar smaller, but for that query, all the fields have links between the tables through Primary Keys. Furthermore, I received these data through a data feed, and I decided to maintain their struct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't even know where to begin. The basic problem is that you are counting in your SELECT clause. This means that for **each record** in leagues (main query), you are executing 3 other big queries (not to mention all the regex). You're not giving your server a chance.
Move your counting from SELECT to FROM (make them join tables).

UPDATE: Here's what I mean:

```
SELECT leagues.feed_league_id, Total.cnt
FROM leagues 
  JOIN countries ON countries.country_id=leagues.country_id 
  JOIN (SELECT l1.feed_league_id, COUNT(DISTINCT m2.match_id) as cnt
         FROM `matches` AS m2
          LEFT JOIN stats ON stats.match_id=m2.match_id
          LEFT JOIN leagues AS l1 ON m2.feed_league_id=l1.feed_league_id
         WHERE stats.tipo='Golos1ª2ª' AND m2.status='FT' AND (m2.home_ht_score*1+ m2.away_ht_score*1) >1 AND m2.home_ht_score REGEXP '[0-9]+' AND m2.away_ht_score REGEXP '[0-9]+'
         GROUP BY l1.feed_league_id
        ) AS Total on Total.feed_league_id = leagues.feed_league_id
GROUP BY leagues.feed_league_id
```

As you can see this is only for Total, but it's the same for the other two big queries.

Comment: Hi, Michael. Can you please give me a Hint about moving the counting from SELECT to FROM. Thank you

Comment: Thank you very much, Michael. It worked like a charm. My query took almost 1 minute to execute, now only take 1 or 2 seconds. Again, thank you very much. Cheers

Comment: Glad it worked, but 1-2s is terribly slow in my opinion. Your tables are tiny, you should be able to improve by two orders of magnitude if you remove the weird regex stuff and multiplication from your WHERE clause and thereby allow mysql to use indexes (which you should add if you haven't yet).